# Find changes made only on a feature branch

Tags: git, github

How do I identify the files which were modified on a particular feature branch.

Scenario:

I have been working on git in a data warehouse script environment, where we deploy the source code to different environments for testing, we do not have a compile procedure.

We have about 30 feature branches and we trace back to the master branch to check if any feature branch has gone live and to keep the other feature branches updated with the production code.

At this moment, we are picking changes between 2 commit points on a feature branch and deploying the modified files, using the below command.

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only ${OLDCOMMIT}..${NEWCOMMIT} | sort | uniq > $FileList
```

However, this is making us test the scripts which were modified on other branches as well.

we want to minimize the testing activity by just picking changes that were modified on the current feature branch and deploy these files for testing.

And the script can ignore the files that were modified on other branches, as those scripts would have been tested by other feature branch developers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple diff command to do this:

```
git diff master HEAD --name-status
```

Where `HEAD` is your current branch. If you want to each commit that's in `feature` but not in `master`, then you can use a revision range instead:

```
git log master..HEAD --name-status
```

You can read more about using [revision/commit ranges from the Pro Git guide](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges).